# what is the final javascript event that gets fired in the page loading process, MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

what is the `javascript` event that gets fired after loading a `view` and also what is sequence of the `events` that get fire in a `view` load?

thanks

Comment: MVC does not trigger any JS Code after loading. Answer to your question depends upon the layout page. If your view doesn't have a layout page then it depends upon what you have in your view

Comment: I think you are looking for load event of the window or document in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [Appliction Lifecycle](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) for MVC.